# Performance - checking if container is empty before doing operations on it?

Tags: c++, performance, containers

Is there a significant difference between doing this...

```
if ( !myVector.empty()) {
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i ) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

and this

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

if the vector is empty? What is the cost of this on an empty vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `size` and `empty` are constant time for vectors.  So most of the time (non-empty vectors), the first one just adds a small, constant amount of work.  The second is clearly cleaner, and probably negligibly more efficient on average.

Answer (score 1):

vector::size is required to be O(1) complexity. So for any reasonable implementation, for VECTORS, you can skip the calls to empty().

A reasonable implementation of a vector would look something like this:

```
class vector { 
    private:
        size_t m_size;

    public:
        size_t size() {
            return m_size;
        }

        bool empty() {
            return m_size == 0;
        }
};
```

Comment: There is no complexity requirement for `vector::size()`.  There is merely a recommendation that it _should_ have constant complexity (and, I can't imagine a reasonable implementation of `vector` where it wouldn't have constant complexity).  Once C++0x is published, then `size()` will be required to have constant complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for performance, why do you need to call the method size in for loop? Why don't you get the value before the loop starts ?

size_t size = myvector.size();

As far as your question, others have already replied.

Answer (score 0):

```
i < myVector.size();
```

Will cause the loop to die before running on an empty vector.  Anything more is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, empty() is faster than comparing size() against zero

That's a rule mentioned by Effective STL

Comment: Meyers says, "empty is a constant-time operation for all standard containers, but for some list implementations, size may take linear time.", which is true.  However, this does *not* apply for `vector`, where both are constant time.  Clearly, calling `size` repeatedly for a `list` would be a bad idea.